# When to close connection to database in MongoDB when using callback functions inside NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The following code gives the error 'Topology is closed, please connect at processWaitQueue'.

```
model.find(function(err,x){
  if(err)
  { 
    console.log(err);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(x);
  }
});
mongoose.connection.close();
```

But the following code works fine:

```
model.find(function(err,x){
  if(err)
  { 
    console.log(err);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log(x);

    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
});
```

Does closing the connection prevent the callback function from working?

Comment: The answer for the explanation is given down below. Why do you want to close the connection with DB? Generally that shouldn't be the way to go about it, is our backend not regularly doing DB operations.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Actually, I am learning back end development and new to MongoDB. I was just trying out things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` method is asynchronous and the callback function is executed **after** the `find` method finished. In the first snippet, the connection to the database is closed while the `find` method has not finished yet and you receive an error. In the second snippet, you close the connection after receiving the result from `find` so it worked.

Comment: If you find the answer is helpful, you can upvote or mark it as accepted. Thanks :)